# Sending an object to a service through Intent without binding

Tags: android

Is is possible to send an object to an Android Service through an Intent without actually binding to the service?  Or maybe another way for the Service to access Objects...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can call startService(Intent) like this:

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
intent.putExtra("object", obj);
startService(intent);
```

The object you want to send must implement Parcelable (you can refer to this [Percelable guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html))

```
class MyObject extends Object implements Parcelable {

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

And with the Service, in the method onStart() or onStartCommand() for api level 5 and newer, you can get the object:

```
MyObject obj = intent.getParcelableExtra("object");
```

That's all :)

Comment: How do I send more than a single data value to the Parcel?  I have two Strings I need to send.

Comment: intent.putExtra("my.first.string", "something");
intent.putExtra("my.second.string", "something else");

Comment: This is still not working for me.  I have done all of the above but am still having problems.  How am I meant to pass the entire state of the object over through Parcelable?  I know I can send basic types like String and Arrays but by object contains more complex classes than just these.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to implement **Parcelable** and your object is serializable

use this

**In the sender Activiy**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MyActivity.class);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("my object", myObject);

intent.putExtras(bundle);

startActivity(intent);
```

**In the receiver:**

```
myObject = (MyObject) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("my object");
```

Works fine for me try it. But the object must be serializable :)

Comment: For me if worked, but I had to change something, on the sending part:

`intent.putExtra("passed object", bundle.getSerializable("my object"));`

And on the receiving part:

`myObject = (MyObject) intent.getExtras().getSerializable("passed object");`

Answer (score 1):

Like Bino said, you need to have your custom object implement the Parcelable interface if you want to pass it to a service via an intent. This will make the object "serializable" in an Android IPC-wise sense so that you can pass them to an Intent's object putExtra(String, Parcelable) call.

For simple primitive types, there's already a bunch of setExtra(String, *primitive type*) methods. As I understand you, however, this is not an option for you which is why you should go for a Parcel.